# Modified Date in Site Contents was shown wrongly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

a list no one has touched for over a year might say "Modified 23 hours ago". It seems as though lists and libraries are being "touched" by some background process, changing the modified time incorrectly.

When I checked IIS logs the url was last time accessed by service account.

What would be the issue Can anyone please suggest me?

Environment : Sharepoint2013 on-premise.

Comment: Have you created any timer job that accesses data and modify it?

Comment: No we have not created !

Comment: this site is for office 365 not for sharepoint 2013: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/15112005-modified-dates-in-site-contents-should-reflect-con